# Multi label classification using meka java

Tags: java, multilabel-classification

Can anyone help with full documentation for classifying a multi label dataset using meka java code..i have to train 80% data first and then test 20% data.How to do this with meka?It will be really if anyone can help.Here is what my dataset look like,1st six attributes are class

```
     @attribute IS_PROTECTION_binarized {0,1}
     @attribute IS_PRICING_binarized {0,1}
     @attribute IS_ERROR_binarized {0,1}
     @attribute IS_USAGE_binarized {0,1}
     @attribute IS_COMPATIBILITY_binarized {0,1}
     @attribute IS_RESOURCES_binarized {0,1}
     @attribute text string

     @data
     0,0,1,0,1,0,'keeps crashing since i upgraded my android this game keeps crashing'
     0,0,0,0,0,0,'addictive i first became a fan of this game when i got an app that u had to earn coins to unlock diffrent colored lights how u got coins was to play games and it just happened tbat one of the mini games was this kind of game'
     0,1,0,0,0,0,'ad free port of the original open source game'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scikit-multilearn for that, the class [LabelPowerset](http://scikit.ml/api/skmultilearn.problem_transform.lp.html) will do the trick, just select a base multi-class classifier. Your probably need to do something with the text attribute though, so using a pipeline might be important.

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import LabelPowerset
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

# initialize LabelPowerset multi-label classifier with a RandomForest
classifier = LabelPowerset(
    classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100),
    require_dense = [False, True]
)

# train
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

The pipeline could look like [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/grid_search_text_feature_extraction.html) :

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', classifier),
])
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.I wish i could do do it in python but i have to use java.I am using Mulan and it worked.Thank you anyway.